# How come Twitter, Facebook, and Google+ does not display on chooserIntent?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, twitter

I am trying to add Twitter, Facebook and Google Plus to my chooserIntent, and all I am getting are email, gmail, and messaging options. I have different messages depending upon which social media is selected. I believe I am missing something to force these apps on my list. My test device has all three of these apps installed too.

I call shareIntent() method for this.

```
private Intent shareIntent() {
        List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

        String shareMsg = "Message 1";

        String emailMsg = "Message 2";

        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
        for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
            String packageName = app.activityInfo.packageName;
            Log.d(TAG, "packageName(" + packageName +")");
            Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            targetedShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, 
                    "SUBJECT");

            if (TextUtils.equals(packageName, "com.twitter.android")) {
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
                        shareMsg);
            } else if (TextUtils.equals(packageName, "com.facebook.android")) {
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
                        shareMsg);
            } else if (TextUtils.equals(packageName, "com.google.android.apps.plus")) {
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
                        shareMsg);
            } else if (TextUtils.equals(packageName, "com.google.android.gm")) {
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, 
                        new String[] {"email@hotmail.com", "email@gmail.com"});
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
                        emailMsg);
            } else if (TextUtils.equals(packageName, "com.android.email")) {
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, 
                        new String[] {"email@hotmail.com", "email@gmail.com"});
            } else if (TextUtils.equals(packageName, "com.android.ms")) {
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
                        shareMsg);
            }

            targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
        }
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), 
                "Share via");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, 
                targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        startActivity(chooserIntent);
        return shareIntent;
    }
```

Comment: Check out my answer any try accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution. Take a look. Thanks to everyone that helped.

```
private Intent shareIntent() {
    List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

    String shareMsg = "Message 1";

    String emailMsg = "Message 2";

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
    for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
        String packageName = app.activityInfo.packageName;
        Log.d(TAG, "packageName(" + packageName +")");
        Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        targetedShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, 
                "Subject");

    if (TextUtils.equals(packageName, "com.google.android.gm")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gmail: " + app.activityInfo.name);
        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, 
                new String[] {"email@hotmail.com", "email@gmail.com"});
        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
                emailMsg);
    } else if (TextUtils.equals(packageName, "com.android.email")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "email: " + app.activityInfo.name);
        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, 
                new String[] {"email@hotmail.com", "email@gmail.com"});
    } else if (TextUtils.equals(packageName, "com.android.mms")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "text msg: " + app.activityInfo.name);
        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
                shareMsg);
    }

        targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
        targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
    }

    Intent facebookIntent = getShareIntent("facebook", "Tip Calculator", shareMsg);
    if(facebookIntent != null)
        targetedShareIntents.add(facebookIntent);

    Intent twitterIntent = getShareIntent("twitter", "Tip Calculator", shareMsg);
    if(twitterIntent != null)
        targetedShareIntents.add(twitterIntent);

    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), 
            "Share via");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, 
            targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivity(chooserIntent);
    return shareIntent;
}
```

And you need this other method as well.

```
private Intent getShareIntent(String type, String subject, String text) 
{
    boolean found = false;
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");

    // gets the list of intents that can be loaded.
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
    System.out.println("resinfo: " + resInfo);
    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
        for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(type) || 
                    info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(type) ) {
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,  subject);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,     text);
                share.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            return null;
        return share;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try out with the below PackageNames

For Twitter:

```
  if ("com.twitter.android.PostActivity".equals(app.activityInfo.name))
```

For Facebook:

```
   if ((app.activityInfo.name).contain("facebook"))
```

For Gmail:

```
 if ((app.activityInfo.name).contain("gmail"))
```

Check out [HERE](http://vnstep.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/share-via-android/)

Comment: Looked promising, but it does not bring up the options. The link you send is helpful, but I need to change out my code.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder Let me know if it helped or not ?

Comment: No, this still does not work. But I am checking out my conditional statements. As it turns out, only email and gmail have true conditions. So my information may not be correct. I will try some new conditions, although yours did not work either.